# WPF: Visual studio like error buttons

Tags: wpf, button, icons, counter

I want to get this.

[buttons http://www.shrani.si/f/X/6Y/24Jhn9D3/buttns.png](http://www.shrani.si/f/X/6Y/24Jhn9D3/buttns.png)

Everything works so far, buttons act as filter and are bind to the grid control.
All i want is the icons and counter on the button.
Whats the correct way of implementing those?

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="IsErrorShown" Margin="4" Width="100" Content="{lex:LocText Errors, Assembly=Client}">
```

I have tried adding image like this:

```
            <ToggleButton x:Name="IsErrorShown" Margin="4" Width="100" Content="{lex:LocText Errors, Assembly=Client}">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="Resources/Warning"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ToggleButton>
```

but i get error that prop. Content is defined more then once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A WPF Button (or ToggleButton) is a content control, into which you can put anything.

I haven't checked, but these buttons probably have a horizontal stack panel or a DockPanel, with an Image and then one or two TextBlocks.   You could make a template for these, and also use binding to set the TextBlock Text content from your viewmodel.

Snoop ( http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ ) is a great tool for finding out how other people have built things in WPF.

The Adam Nathan WPF book is *excellent*, and if you don't have it you should get it.   http://www.amazon.co.uk/Windows-Presentation-Foundation-Unleashed-WPF/dp/0672328917

Here's an example:

```
  <ToggleButton Height="24" Width="100">
    <DockPanel>
      <Image Source="c:\\temp\\me.jpg" Margin="3"/>
      <TextBlock Text="20 Errors"/>
    </DockPanel>
  </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: thanx for your reply. I forgot to mention i have togglebuttons, and since im abit in a hurry i havent got the time to read the entire book. Well, i am going to, i just have to push this problem first.

Comment: I added an example.  Don't forget to vote-up stuff you like, otherwise your teeth will fall out and you'll be covered in boils.